# Recover data from a bricked phone (not yet reset)

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, unbricking

I get this screen from an old android device:

[image]

It has not yet went through a full factory reset so the data is still there. The data (photos) is in internal storage (no sdcard).

Any ideas how to recover data from this?

Comment: maybe if you mention phone model

Comment: @alecxs Actually a tablet, Samsung `SM-T211`

Comment: enter [recovery mode](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-t211-galaxy-tab-3-70/recovery-mode) and install [philz_touch_6.44.9-lt023g.zip](https://mega.nz/folder/oZ1QDDbC#Ko20UNhowwIlXLVFjJsyKw/file/oVMQXSbR) via *"apply update from external storage"* or flash [philz_touch_6.44.9-lt023g.tar.md5](https://mega.nz/folder/oZ1QDDbC#Ko20UNhowwIlXLVFjJsyKw/file/JYVlWSiI) from [Odin](https://androidmtk.com/flash-samsung-stock-rom-using-odin). enter recovery mode again, it looks like [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lt02xxx-cwm-advanced-edition-philz-touch.2653391/post-50438133)

Comment: in PhilZ touch recovery *"Mounts and Storage"* mount /data and /sdcard1. *"Install Zip*" from sdcard [aromafm-1.91.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/cwm-app-2-00-aroma-filemanager-terminal-15022810-open-source.1646108) for file manager. copy your pictures to MicroSD Card. you can also copy files to PC with [adb pull](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) or do a raw dump of ext4 partition *'adb pull /dev/block/platform/sdhci-pxav3.2/by-name/USER data.img'*

Comment: in case you are facing trouble another custom recovery [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-root-t211-twrp-2-7-1-0-kk-unofficial.2503063) v2.7.1.0 is also available for SM-T211. be aware to untick all checkboxes in Odin

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for this. One of my main issue even before I posted here is I couldn't even get to recovery mode. I have been trying the `Volume Up + Home + Power button` routine several times and even `Volume Down` but the screen only gets rebooted to that "Firmware upgrade encountered..." screen over and over. Any other ways to go to recovery?

Comment: try download mode with JIG dongle

Comment: @alecxs I'll try to get one of those then I'll update you, thanks!

Comment: Hey @alecxs, I managed to get a JIG dongle but unfortunately it did not work on this SM-T211. Though the JIG dongle worked a different Samsung phone when I tested it. I guess I am SOL?

Comment: watch youtube disassembly video how to open, disconnect battery, connect JIG dongle, hold Volume Down + Home and connect battery. Repeat with usb-cable if still no luck

Comment: @alecxs Next level stuff right there. It may take a while before if I try that but I'll let you know if I am successful. Thanks again.